# Slinky-like worm/leech identification

Tags: species-identification

In my mulch bed today I came across a tiny red worm, between $\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ an inch long. It moved across the ground by sitting upright on one end, waving the other end back and forth (presumably for some momentum), and then flipping over and standing on the other end. It did this motion flipping end-over-end, kind of like a slinky. Observed in the Chesapeake Bay region.

I haven't been able to find anything on this little creature through searches. An article about [leaping nematodes](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/artful-amoeba/leaping-nematodes-tiny-worms-jump-to-reach-next-victim/#:%7E:text=The%20record%20high%20jump%20is,of%20a%20new%20host%20insect.&text=Nematodes%20are%20tiny%20animals%20that%20are%20also%20called%20roundworms.) is the only thing remotely in the neighborhood of what I saw but the motion described is different and these sound far too small to be the same creature. Any ideas what this is?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Can you get pictures of your worm — macro images in particular might be helpful for this identification. You might also want to check out [iNaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/) — that site is much more focused on identifications and I think you are more likely to a definitive answer there.

Comment: Hi @tyersome, thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately I wasn't able to get a picture at the time or locate one again since then but will continue trying. I'll give the app a try I can get a pic. Thanks.

Comment: Did they resemble these "jumping worms" ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrGnUFDXuyQ  this video is not as red or as jumpy as I'm imagining yours to be

Comment: @JimN, very different. This was tiny by comparison to those, less than half an inch, and stood upright, never on it's side like a normal worm. Still have had no luck spotting again to get a picture.

Comment: @IPoiler how about this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFkz-L4wNT0 (starting at the 25 second mark) or this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xVk87DZB6NY (3:30 mark). Neither of these is red, though, but how does the size and shape compare?

Comment: @JimN, not quite but slightly more disturbing to watch (0.o). Looked a bit like a miniaturized single [red/orange anemone polyp](https://cdn.britannica.com/s:1500x700,q:85/09/4009-004-61B594DA/sea-anemone-genus-rock-Tealia.jpg). Great work tracking down a potential hit in a video with less than 70 views though.

Comment: @IPoiler to be honest, I've spent a few hours on this :) which I don't mind. I've learned a lot along the way. I can't figure out what would match your description. But there are some parasitic worms/maggots that affect specific plants. I know you described your worms as being in your mulch, but did it seem like they were coming out of a certain plant? the roots? or concentrated around a certain something decaying in compost? Or was it around a particular kind of large tree?

Comment: @JimN after doing some reading on locomotion in different types of invertebrates, I'm pretty confident that what I encountered was some type of tiny [leech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-6LI6mrrng). It didn't have quite the inchworm gait like the one in the video, seeming to instead flip from one sucker to the other like a slinky. It did mostly stand up on one end waving around similar to that one though.